# Docker DB Migration/Deployment to DigitalOcean

Tags: docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-machine

Warning: I am fairly new to docker and cloud hosting, this is likely a dumb question.

I have a local web app which has 3 images associated with it, the app itself, the db and a phpmyadmin image. All works well locally, and if I transfer all the files to my digital ocean droplet and bring up my containers it works fine there as well, but this is not how I want to deploy having every file from every library residing in my droplet.

I have been experimenting with creating a docker-machine on my droplet and deploying my containers remotely to it. This seems to work fine other than the fact that my db image does not reference my database and is simply an empty db. I tried to migrate the db in this fashion which I saw in a tutorial:

```
docker-compose run --rm web db:create db:migrate
```

But got the following error, I assume this is because my dev machine is running Windows 10 not Linux, but I cannot find anywhere what the equivalent command would be for a Windows machine.

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"db:create\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I know I am probably missing something really stupid and easy but I am having difficulties figuring out how to migrate the data for my db image. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
As requested here is my docker-compose:

```
    version: "3.4"

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
volumes:
  data:
```

UPDATE #2:
transfered db file to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (I tried this yesterday too but couldn't get it working) and created a new production docker-compose-prod.yml I must be missing something still though as the DB is still empty. Below is my new docker-compose-prod.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is sound.

Actually, you can take it a further step by automating the Droplet provisioning to e.g. use a container-oriented OS and access your Compose file. But that's not this question ;-)

I think it is not relevant that you're using Windows and probably makes little difference; it may require some answer tweaks but that's about it.

The challenge is that you need to move (or recreate) the database state on the remote machine. There are several ways that the DB state could be persisted: in-container (not ideal); using volume mounts (good), other.

Each is "moveable" but it would help if you could add your Compose file to your question so that we may see which approach is being used.

In full-disclosure Im not familiar with the approach that you referencesd but that does not mean that it's inaccurate; I'm just not familiar with it.

#### Update: `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

See: "Initializing a fresh instance" on [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

So, any files within that directory are run to initialize the database container when it's created from the image.

In your Compose file you mount your host's `./data` directory into this file. Presumably that directory contains >=1 file that performs your intended initialization.

> **NB** The section `volumes: data:` at the end of the Compose file appears redundant. You're actually using a host-mounted directory `./data` not this volume.

When you run the Compose file on the Droplet, those files aren't present and you'll need to copy them.

The simplest way to do this is to use scp and this provides 2 alternatives:

**Either** retain the `data` directory:

```sh
IP=[DROPLET-IP]
scp -r ./data root@${IP}:/data
```

> **NB** The remote destination is `/data` not `./data`. You will need to revise the Compose file on the Droplet (!) too:
> `volumes: - /data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

**Or** move the files directly to the Droplet's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`:

```sh
scp -r ./data root@${IP}/docker-entrypointy-initdb.d
```

> **NB** Now there's no need for the volume mapping. You may remove:
>     `volumes: - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

#### Update: repro (works)

I used a tweaked `docker-compose.yaml` but it's essentially the same:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Then `mkdir ${PWD}/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and created a file in it called `freddie.sql`:

```
create database if not exists frederik;

use frederik;

create table treats (
 TreatID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 TreatName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (TreatId));

insert into treats (TreatName)
values
 ("Dried Salmon"),
 ("Meatballs");
```

Then `docker-compose rm --force && docker-compose up`

I was able to browse the adminer UI (`:8080`), login (`root`|`mypass`) and browse the database `frederik`:

[image]

Comment: OK, I'm going to update my answer to make it easier to respond.

Comment: Updated my post again

Comment: The `db` service's `volumes` is extraneous. Please remove it. I'm surprised it's valid and it may be mount-overwriting the files you're copying to the Droplet.

Comment: What do you have in the data directory on your host? The `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory should contain SQL scripts (only). These will be used to create the database schema and content when the container is run.

Comment: At first I actually had removed it and tried with no success, then I added it as it appears in my question also without success. Either way, still an empty db :(. The only thing in the data and docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directories is a .sql db script.

Comment: Ugh... I'm sorry.... Duplicate the volume mapping... You want the Droplet's ...initdb.d mapped into the DB container's directory on the Droplet

Comment: You'll want: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` for the DB service's `volumes`

Comment: You copy the SQL script into the Droplet's directory and then map the Droplet"s host's directory into the same directory path on the DB container running on the Droplet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208095/discussion-between-mgrenier-and-dazwilkin).

Comment: OK. I tried it and it works for me :-) One thing (!) you may need to. The initialization only works when the container is first initialized. Using Compose, the container will not be reinitialized each time you run `docker-compose up`. You can remove the container(s) using `docker-compose rm` and then `docker-compose up`. Does that work? Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, all is good now. I appreciate the time spent helping me with this!